# GraphicsMagick using nodejs not returning correct image

Tags: css, node.js, image, imagemagick

I am using GraphicsMagick.

This is the image:

https://hbr.org/resources/images/article_assets/hbr/1405/F1405A_A.gif

which I used for cropping:

[image]

My code is here:

```
 gm(request(url), "myimage.jpeg")
    .resize(270, 270, '^')
    .gravity('Center')
    .quality(50)
    .crop(270,270)
    .compress('JPEG')
    .flatten()
    .stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                //upload the file
                file.uploadFileFromGm(fileDetails, stdout, cb);
            }
        });
```

The code is working fine.

But I got an transparent image which is empty on left side.

I got the following image as a result:

[image]

Why is white background not working in the transparent portion? Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input image is a `GIF` and has transparency. Your output file is a `JPEG` which cannot support transparency, so GraphicsMagick has rendered the transparent pixels as black - the default background colour.

You have two choices:

1. Store your image as `GIF`, or `PNG` which can represent transparency
2. Change the background colour to solid (non-transparent) white and store as `JPEG`.

Which one you choose depends on where/how you plan to use the image and whether the background behind the image must be visible where you are going to use it.

Comment: ["2 more votes from other users are needed to undelete this question"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12620113/359307). (Thx!)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

http://www.w3docs.com/tools/image-optimiser/