# Is there a way to search a pdf for a mathematical expression (e.g. LaTeX)?

Tags: pdf, latex, expression

I have a pdf that was created with latex.  I see something that would be generated by u_t in LaTeX math mode.  I would like to find other instances of this in the pdf.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a sample pdf? This does not look like a programming question by the way.

Comment: Oh yeah, sry, I wasn't sure what SE site to put it on... I meant to mention that.  Sample pdf: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5542-recurrent-models-of-visual-attention.pdf

Comment: I would try generating a pdf with just the expression that you want to search, then [decompress that pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620113/example-pdf-language-code-which-helps-to-study-the-official-pdf-specification/12630604#12630604) and open it using a text editor to see how latex represented the expression (you will need to know a little bit about the format for this), then decompress your original pdf and search for the same pattern there.

Comment: seems like all formulas are made using special glyphs. But to find them among other glyphs could be not easy without decompressing and parsing  the document into pdf objects.